# How can I check the PID of a X-server in another virtual terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, xorg, x-server, pid

I am trying to open a program in a naked X-server on a different virtual terminal.
I am using ubuntu 9.10.

The command I'm using is this.

```
openvt -f -s -- `X :2 & '/path/to/program' -display :2`;
```

Now, when the program shuts down I want the X-server to be killed as well.

So my question is this: How can I save the PID of the new X-server (X :2) to then later kill it?

It is going to be used in a normal shell script.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, `$!` is `the  process ID of the most recently executed back-ground (asynchronous) command`.

```
Sombrero:Documents polleyj$ xterm &
[1] 41316
Sombrero:Documents polleyj$ KILLPID=$!
Sombrero:Documents polleyj$ echo $KILLPID
41316
Sombrero:Documents polleyj$ kill $KILLPID
Sombrero:Documents polleyj$
[1]+  Killed                  xterm
Sombrero:Documents polleyj$
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using openvt, you could use [Xephyr](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Xephyr) to open a nested X sesssion. That would make it easier to manage it afterwards.

Use `sudo apt-get install xserver-xephyr` to install it.

Couple that with using `$!` to grab the process ID as James suggested.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to store pgrep -f 'X :2' in a variable mypid.
Then I simply killed $mypid..